# Saving Files With Slightly Different Names

Tags: r, loops

I have the following loop that runs 5 different Random Forest Models on 5 different datasets (these datasets are in a list object):

```
# Base Loop : Works Fine
results_1 <- list()
results_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:5){
    model_i <- randomForest(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]])

    predict_i <- data.frame(predict(model_i , test_set ,type="prob"))
    predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
    
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i
    results_2[[i]] <- predict_i 
}
```

**I would like to save each of these models (in "my documents") using the "model_i.RDS" format. If this were to work, there would be 5 RDS files (model_1.RDS, model_2.RDS, model_3.RDS, model_4.RDS, model_5.RDS) in saved/created in "my documents".**

I thought R would pick up on this by itself seeing as I have defined the "index i" already:

```
# Method 1: Does Not Work
results_1 <- list()
results_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:5){
    
    
    model_i <- randomForest(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]])

    saveRDS(model_i, "model_i.RDS") 
    
    predict_i <- data.frame(predict(model_i , test_set ,type="prob"))
    predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
    
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i
    results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
}
```

But this is only saving a single "RDS" file.

I then tried to be more explicit with the saving command:

```
# Method 2: Also Not Working
wd = getwd()

results_1 <- list()
results_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:5){
    model_i <- randomForest(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]])
    
    saveRDS(model_i, paste0("wd", paste("model_", i, ".RDS")))
            
    predict_i <- data.frame(predict(model_i , test_set ,type="prob"))
    
    predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
    
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i
    results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
}
```

But this still isn't working (a single file is being saved instead of 5 files).

**Can someone please show me how to fix this problem?**

**Note** : Sample Data for Problem:

```
 library(randomForest)
    
    test_set = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), height = rnorm(100,100,100), weight = rnorm(100,100,100), salary = rnorm(100,100,100)) 
    
    train_data_1 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), height = rnorm(100,100,100), weight = rnorm(100,100,100), salary = rnorm(100,100,100)) 
    
    train_data_2 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), height = rnorm(100,100,100), weight = rnorm(100,100,100), salary = rnorm(100,100,100)) 
    
    train_data_3 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), height = rnorm(100,100,100), weight = rnorm(100,100,100), salary = rnorm(100,100,100)) 
    
    train_data_4 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), height = rnorm(100,100,100), weight = rnorm(100,100,100), salary = rnorm(100,100,100)) 
    
    train_data_5 = data.frame( class = as.factor(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=100)), height = rnorm(100,100,100), weight = rnorm(100,100,100), salary = rnorm(100,100,100)) 
    
# data used in question
 X = list(train_data_1, train_data_2, train_data_3, train_data_4, train_data_5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last attempt, the OP used `paste`, but there was no `/` between the working directory and file name - safer to use `file.path`.  In addition, the `wd` used was `"wd"` which will be taken literally instead of the value stored in the object.  Instead, it can be `paste0(wd, "/model_", i, ".RDS")`

```
results_1 <- vector('list', 5)
results_2 <- vector('list', 5)
for (i in 1:5){
    model_i <- randomForest(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]])
    
    saveRDS(model_i, file.path(wd, paste0("model_", i, ".RDS")))
            
    predict_i <- data.frame(predict(model_i , test_set ,type="prob"))
    
    predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
    
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i
    results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
}
```

-output

[image]

Comment: @ akrun: thank you so much for your answer! Is there any reason you chose vector('list', 5) instead or just "list"? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob it is better to initialize a list of fixed length instead of elongating the list on the loop